# Getting an type conversion error while using linq in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, type-conversion

I am trying to get the data from SQL Server database.

I have a table called `Standard` in my database. It has three columns `StandardID`, `StandardName`, and `Description`.

I have a combobox in which I fill the values of `StandardName`

Here is the code :

```
Using db As New SchoolDBEntities
    ComboSelectStandardToEdit.DataSource = db.Standards.ToList()
    ComboSelectStandardToEdit.ValueMember = "StandardID"
    ComboSelectStandardToEdit.DisplayMember = "StandardName"
End Using
```

Now I have 2 textboxes called `txtStandardName` and `txtDescription`.

I want to fill the values of these 2 textboxes based on selected `StandardName` from the combobox.

Here is the code I tried :

```
Using db As New SchoolDBEntities
            Dim standard = From s In db.Standards
                            Where s.StandardId = CInt(ComboSelectStandardToEdit.SelectedValue)
                            Select s

            txtStandardName.Text = CType(standard, Standard).StandardName
        End Using
```

but unfortunately I got error :

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`` `1[EF_WinForms_VB.Standard]' to type 'EF_WinForms_VB.Standard'. ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
Dim standard = (From s In db.Standards
    Where s.StandardId = CInt(ComboSelectStandardToEdit.SelectedValue)
    Select s)
    .FirstOrDefault

txtStandardName.Text = standard.StandardName
```

your Linq query currently is returing a projection which could contain multiple entries.  By explicitly requesting the first object of the projection, you won't need to cast your standard before accessing it's value.

Comment: T get this error at runtime : Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: seems this may be related to your where clause, at one point you are using `StandardID` and in the other you are using `StandardId` which isn't a property on the object

Comment: @user2524507: You probaby have to extract the `CInt` conversion out of the query before the `Dim standard ...` line: `Dim standardId = CInt(ComboSelectStandardToEdit.SelectedValue)` and then the `Where` clause: `Where s.StandardId = standardId`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

Dim standard = (From s In db.Standards.AsEnumerable
    Where s.StandardId = Convert.ToInt32(ComboSelectStandardToEdit.SelectedValue)
    Select s)
    .FirstOrDefault

txtStandardName.Text = standard.StandardName

Hope it helps.